# Why tellg() returning -1 at th end of code?

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    system("cls");
    fstream obj;
    obj.open("today.txt",ios::in);
    char ch; 
    while (obj)
    {
        cout<<endl<<"file pointer at :"<<obj.tellg();
        obj>>ch;
    }
    cout<<endl<<obj.tellg();
    return 0;
}
```

output :

```
file pointer at :0
file pointer at :1
file pointer at :2
file pointer at :3
file pointer at :4
file pointer at :5
file pointer at :7
file pointer at :8
file pointer at :9
file pointer at :10
file pointer at :11
-1
```

Comment: What would you expect and why? What does the documentation say about the return value?

Comment: The `while` loop ends when `obj` evaluates to false. This happens when an error flag is set. So the last `obj.tellg()` is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tellg` is returning -1 because it has encountered an error while reading the obj!! As `while` loop exits once the file has reached its end (no more data to read) and so obj is null and hence `tellg` return -1.

Refer to this site for more information-
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/tellg/

Comment: Accept any of the answer which helped you, to mark the question answered!

Comment: sure .....i am new here soon understand all the functions

Answer (score 2):

From the docs:

> Return value:
>
> The current position in the stream. If either the stream buffer
> associated to the stream does not support the operation, or if it
> fails, the function returns -1.

So `tellg` is "failing". A common  reason is if you hit the end of the stream (a file here). This makes sense since you iterate until the end of the stream just before.